# How do you access the line-in sound card within a docker containder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, docker, centos7

How do you access the **line-in** sound card within a containder docker.

HOST: **Centos 7**

CONTAINER DOCKER: **Centos 7**

I would like to do this in **Ubuntu** host too?

Comment: How do you access it in a Linux?

Comment: I need to know how access line-in from host inside docker container

Comment: The same way you do it on a standard Linux, you may need to mount some devices with `docker run -v`